# Is 'damn you' abusive or offensive?

Tags: word-usage

I would say in jest to someone, *"Damn you!, you always get your way."*

He insisted that I was being abusive. Since my tone or tenor did not convey it, I put it down to his studying in a Catholic school.

My question is, in Christian dominated countries today, is 'damn you' offensive or can it be used in jest?

Comment: Would you use it to the Pope?

Comment: I would not say a lot of things to the Pope, if that's the rule we are going by!

Comment: This is not really a useful question - any answer will be opinion based.

Comment: Well even if it is opinion based, a speaker from a non-English speaking country, shall certainly benefit.I am asking because I need to know, there would be others like me, am sure.

Comment: But there isn't an answer. I might say it is inoffensive. But many of the population would be offended. So it is entirely opinion based... so not useful for Stack Exchange

Comment: I've got an unequivocal answer! Google: **offensive**: causing someone to feel deeply hurt, upset, or angry. 'Damn you' had this effect on your 'someone', ergo it must be offensive.

Comment: I don't understand why this is closed.  Are questions of whether a term is generally considered offensive or vulgar considered off topic here in general?  I see many such questions; my impression is the ones for which the answer is clearly "yes" get answered (for example https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/408593/is-it-offensive-to-call-people-with-autism-mentally-disabled and lots of others), and the ones that don't get downvoted and/or closed.  That seems pretty strange to me; assuming the questions are being asked in good faith, aren't they all equally worthy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose I've sat through one too-many mandatory in-house session on "bullying,"
but I do feel the answer to OP's question lies in the relationship between the two persons involved.  If OP said, "Damn you!  You always get your way" to a small child who has been been taught that Christianity is the "One True View", then it was abusive.  If the comment was directed toward a peer or a boss with well-known non-religious views, there is no abuse possible because the listener would not hear the comment as any kind of a real threat.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's no modern Christian sect that believes mortals have the ability to damn people other than themselves. "Damn you" is therefore more of a declaration that the speaker wishes or expects the other party to be damned by their own actions - which may well be offensive, but it's not a *threat*, as such.

Answer (score 2):

IMO it's the individual not their religious affiliation. I know both religious and non that would go either way with your reply. For example, my wife who's Catholic and has been to nothing but Catholic institutions has the mouth of a sailor. She would not be offended by your comment.

Comment: I think you need more than an anecdote to explain the position here.

Comment: @robusto Did I misinterpret the guidelines?
<br>
"But avoid …
Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or **personal experience.**"