# Is it offensive to call people with autism "mentally disabled"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, terminology, word-usage

I recently posted a post on Reddit about my app for people with autism, cerebral palsy and other *diseases*. Someone pointed out usage of "mental handicap" as offensive, but the comment has disappeared before I read it. Are these considered offensive?

- Mental handicap
- Mental disorder
- Mental disease
- Mentally disabled
- Person with special needs
- Mentally challenged

Could you please help me? I don't want to offend anybody. What are the best/"safest" terms to use?

Comment: Could you provide some context please, Ondrej? What do your users do with the app? I'm struggling to think what features autism and CP have in common, except that they're both associated with the brain. The only one of the terms you used that might fit both conditions is "special needs". But really, why are you even making an app for these people if you don't know that Cerebral Palsy is a physical condition, rather than mental? Also, many people would question whether autistic spectrum conditions are a 'disease' or not.

Comment: CP is most of the time connected with a mental condition, too. The project: www.pinfhry.com. I'm 15 and I am trying to help people with special needs. My mom's cousin has CP and I started the app development for her when I was 11.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to be too critical - what you're doing is a very worthy cause - but of course be careful not to offend (or over-generalise). Good luck with your app :)

Comment: You're tip-toeing through a minefield.

Comment: The best solution might be to be more specific and indicating what exact problem or difficulty your app is aimed at, e.g. "people with problems doing X". But you don't include enough information to be sure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about the English language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Mental handicap** - offensive. (period)

**Mental disorder** - not true of Cerebral Palsy (it affects physical movement only in a majority of cases) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerebral_palsy. Not universally accepted as true of all autism. https://www.mencap.org.uk/learning-disability-explained/conditions/autism-and-aspergers-syndrome

**Mental disease** - Not true of Cerebral Palsy (see above). Not universally accepted as true of all autism.

**Mentally disabled** -  Not true of Cerebral Palsy (see above). Not universally accepted as true of all autism.

**Person with special needs** - is *not generally considered offensive*. But not everyone with the conditions you mentioned literally has 'special' needs. Many autistic and CP people live a full life in all areas without special support.

**Mentally challenged** - Not necessarily true of either condition. It implies they're stupid... when lot's of very bright people have one of these conditions.

The correct term to use in your app is ***neurological condition***,

Answer (score 2):

A few decades ago, the terms mental handicap or mentally handicapped were standard ways of describing mental disability. But they are now likely to cause offence and you should avoid using them. They've been replaced in all official contexts by the less negative term learning difficulties.

Comment: That's interesting, Robert. In which country has _**learning difficulties**_ been declared the acceptable term? A person diagnosed with [_**mental illness**_](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mental_illness/) [ODO] needn't have a learning disability. Some are very intelligent and quick studies but have behavioural issues that can hinder their efforts to be educated. Still, creating a separate category like _**has difficulties fitting in**_ for them might do more harm than good.

Comment: Mental illness is as common as physical illness. if the term mental illness is a taboo word then it is the problem of the taboo system for censoring those words; not of who is using the forbidden word. Mental health issues should not be perceived as forbidden or offensive.

Answer (score 2):

Autism is a complex sensory integration disorder which remains lifelong and nobody likes to being referred with a tag or a name. People with autism require special attention as they tend to shy for any kind of social interactions.

Writing or asking questions about disability needs sensitivity while referring to a third person.

Some of the basic guideline you can follow,

- Refer to disability only when it is related to the story or comes from a reputable source such as medical or licensed professional.
- When possible, seek for the advice from the person or the source.
- Make use of first-language wherever possible.
- Avoid the use of words like diversability and handicapped.

Being a **Sped Teacher at ACCEL**, individuals with autism spectrum are not different rather their perspective of life is vivid. The best kind of advice, if you’re writing or questioning someone, then you should always ask the person on how to refer them.

Comment: All very true and perfectly the best approach to take but the OP wanted to know if any of the phrases listed in the question were offensive. This also implied suggesting a term/expression that would be the most sensitive and least controversial. Sometimes you need a title (or description) for writing or talking about this disorders/disabilities.

Comment: Hi Dorian, please take a look [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) . This in general applies for all Stackexchange sites ...

Answer (score 2):

interestingly; many autistic idividual themselves prefer "autistic person" over "persons with autism". in other words, when it comes about medical diagnosis, many of the autistics tend to use ["**identity-first" language** than the "**person-first language**"](https://wibblywobblyneurounlogicalstuff.com/2017/10/06/person-first-vs-identity-first-language/). It is tricky, but it is due to autistics' experiences and worldview tend to be much different than dypically developing population.

Also many people perceives the way that disability should not be viewed as not a [bad](https://medium.com/@Kathrynpoe/disability-isnt-a-bad-word-7d5e04d93218) or [dirty](https://medium.com/@paperstainedink/disabled-is-not-a-dirty-word-7b30dc4b881b) word. I also witnessed social media posts by some autistic people (or  people at least claimed to be autistic) plead the world to call them disabled instead of diffable.

The realistic answer to this original question is more complicated than the worldview as taught in common literature classes.